# Why Planck's constant is taken equal to $1$ while writing Hamiltonian for a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-constants

Planck's constant is usually taken as $1$ in the Hamiltonian of a quantum system. Can anyone please tell me the advantages of doing so in quantum optics?

Comment: One fewer symbol to lug around (and possibly forget).

Comment: [Natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)

Answer (score 2):

The main idea behind setting these constants $\hbar$, c (speed of light) or $k_{B}$(Boltzmann constant) to 1 is to measure some other related quantity in terms of energy. Setting c = 1 implies, mass and momentum are measured in units of energy ($E = mc^2$). Similarly setting $\hbar =1$ implies we measure length in units of inverse energy ($\because [x,p] = i\hbar$). Setting Boltzmann constant to 1 implies that we measure temperature in units of energy. This formulation makes handling of Hamiltonian simpler